# replace value in data.frame row by row

Tags: r

I want to create a new column where all the entries of x are in, exept for those parts that appear in the column y in the same row.

```
data<-data.frame(x = 
 c("Leo Messi","Frank Ribery","Mats Hummels", "Leo Hummels", "Leo Ribery"),  
 y = c("Leo", "Ribery",  "Mats", NA, "Mama")
)
```

This is the output I want to have. 
The column z is x without the entries of y.
The column q is the parts the were replaced.
It is important that in row 4 Leo gets not replaced. In row 1 is Leo in column y, but that should not lead to replacement.

```
         x         y      z            q
1    Leo Messi    Leo    Messi        Leo 
2 Frank Ribery Ribery    Frank        Ribery
3 Mats Hummels   Mats    Hummels      Mats 
4  Leo Hummels   <NA>    Leo Hummels  <NA>  
5   Leo Ribery   Mama    Leo Ribery   <NA>
```

Comment: Does the substring have to be separated by a space? In other words if y[5] was "Le" should that part of "Leo Hummels" be removed leaving "o Ribery"?

Comment: Only exact matches should be removed. Leo != Le or  Leo != Le_O

Answer (score 3):

I think the following should work. I've used a few packages for vectorization / efficiency

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)

# Replace what we can find (vectorized over pattern)
setDT(data)[, z := trimws(stri_replace_all_fixed(x, y, ""))]

# Insert x into z if y is NA
data[is.na(y), z := x]

# Insert x into q if x != z
data[x != z, q := y]

data
#               x      y           z      q
# 1:    Leo Messi    Leo       Messi    Leo
# 2: Frank Ribery Ribery       Frank Ribery
# 3: Mats Hummels   Mats     Hummels   Mats
# 4:  Leo Hummels     NA Leo Hummels     NA
# 5:   Leo Ribery   Mama  Leo Ribery     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Your data

```
data<-data.frame(x = c("Leo Messi","Frank Ribery","Mats Hummels", "Leo Hummels", "Leo Ribery"), y = c("Leo", "Ribery",  "Mats", NA, "Mama"))

    all<-as.character(data$x)
    to_sub<-as.character(data$y)
    i<-rep(1:length(all))
```

z calculation

```
f_gsub<-function(x,y,i){ gsub(y[i],"",x[i]) }
data$z<-unlist(lapply(i,f_gsub,x=all,y=to_sub))
data[is.na(data$z),"z"]<-as.character(data[is.na(data$z),"x"])
```

q calculation

```
f_grepl<-function(x,y,i){ grepl(y[i],x[i]) }
sub_YN<-as.logical(unlist(lapply(i,f_grepl,x=all,y=to_sub)))
data$q<-NA
data[!is.na(sub_YN),"q"]<-to_sub[sub_YN]
```

data

```
             x      y           z      q
1    Leo Messi    Leo       Messi    Leo
2 Frank Ribery Ribery      Frank  Ribery
3 Mats Hummels   Mats     Hummels   Mats
4  Leo Hummels   <NA> Leo Hummels   <NA>
5   Leo Ribery   Mama  Leo Ribery   <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`, `stringr`, and `stringi`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

data %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% # can be avoided if we use stringsAsFactors = FALSE when creating the data frame
  mutate(z = str_squish(stri_replace_all_fixed(x, y, "")),
         z = case_when(is.na(y) ~ x, TRUE ~ z),
         q = case_when(x %in% z == FALSE ~ y))
```

Returns:

```
             x      y           z      q
1    Leo Messi    Leo       Messi    Leo
2 Frank Ribery Ribery       Frank Ribery
3 Mats Hummels   Mats     Hummels   Mats
4  Leo Hummels   <NA> Leo Hummels   <NA>
5   Leo Ribery   Mama  Leo Ribery   <NA>
```